# Need explanation on this Java syntax

Tags: java, arrays, syntax

Can someone explain what the following does?

```
private HashSet nodes[]; 
nodes = new HashSet[21];
```

I'm a little confused... in the difference between

```
private HashSet nodes = new HashSet;
```

and the above, particularly in terms of the square brackets syntax. Is this an array of HashSets? Because normally I'm used to seeing

```
int[] myarray = new int[21];
```

Or something like that.

Comment: In Java, you *can* declare arrays like `Type foo[]`, but it is much, much more common to see arrays declared as `Type[] foo`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is an array of `HashSets`.

```
HashSet nodes[];
```

is the same as

```
HashSet[] nodes;
```

The difference in where you place the brackets only becomes important when you use commas to declare a bunch of variables at a time:

```
HashSet[] alpha, bravo, charlie; // Three arrays of hashsets
HashSet delta[], echo, foxtrot; // One array (delta) and two hashsets (echo and foxtrot)
```

Comment: So it's equivalent to saying private HashSet[] nodes?

Comment: Yes. In Java the brackets can come in either place.

Comment: @varatis, Java introduced the `Type[]` syntax so that you could put the whole type in one place but also allowed the C style syntax to make it easier for C/C++ programmers to learn Java.

Answer (score 5):

They're just alternatives - both are valid, unfortunately.

Heck, even this would be valid:

```
int[] bad [] = null;
```

That's equivalent to

```
int[][] bad = null;
```

Don't do this, obviously :)

From [section 10.2 of the JLS](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-10.html#jls-10.2):

> The [] may appear as part of the type at the beginning of the declaration, or as part of the declarator for a particular variable, or both.

And

> We do not recommend "mixed notation" in an array variable declaration, where brackets appear on both the type and in declarators.

Basically, use the form that keeps all the type information in one place - the form you're used to. That's the *overwhelmingly* idiomatic form.

Comment: Nothing unfortunate about it when you have long lists of variables.

Comment: @trutheality: What do you mean? I see no benefit in both forms being valid, which makes confusing declarations like the "bad" one valid. I wasn't suggesting arrays themselves are unfortunate - I'm saying that having two different ways of declaring them is unfortunate.

Comment: You seem to prefer the `int[] array;` notation. I'm just pointing out that being able to write a declaration of the form `int number1, number2, array1[], array2[], matrix[][];` is very convenient. Sure, the convenience is marginal but it is there. Especially if you consider that the only negative outcome of allowing both forms is that someone can write confusing code, it isn't much of a downside -- someone will always find a way to write confusing code.

Comment: @trutheality: Eek, I'd *definitely* avoid that. Personally I almost always have a single variable per declaration anyway - it's easier to comment that way. I think the ability to write confusing code is a *great* disadvantage. Sure, it's always going to be *possible* to write confusing code, but a language should do as much as possible to prevent that. I suppose you don't mind being able to write `someOtherThread.sleep(1000);` either?

Comment: Well, keep in mind that when I declare more than three variables in a list like that I indent and line break at the commas, so you can still easily comment. I try to make code both readable and minimal -- there is such a thing as code that is too verbose. `someOtherThread.sleep(1000);` I don't like. Can't come up with a case where calling `someObject.staticMethod();` is useful on the spot, but I thought there was a good reason to allow it. I do think that having something like a `strictly static` modifier would be a very good idea in many cases.

Comment: @trutheality: If you're going to indent an line-break, what's the benefit of using a single statement for the declaration? It sounds like it's taking the same space as using independent declarations, with the downside that you have to do more work to find the type of variable that you're actually declaring.

Comment: It's not about space, it's about clutter. Having a column of, say,  `public static final String` repeated however many times is, IMO, clutter. Write that once, and it's clear that what follows is a list of string constants for your class. I'll agree that it's a matter of taste when it comes down to it.

Comment: @trutheality: I rarely have that many constants in the same class, and I certainly wouldn't want to have their type depend on earlier declarations. As you say, it's a matter of taste - but I can't say I've seen anyone else use that style in the companies I've worked in either... Additionally, that's one situation for *constants* - but we were talking about *arrays*.

Comment: Well, you could imagine some computationally-oriented class or method that uses many `double`s and `double` arrays declared similarly. Having a column of the word `double` ten or 20 times would still look cluttered.

Comment: @trutheality: I think we'll have to agree to disagree about that - and compared with the very real point of confusion, I still say it's a misfeature. (One which I'm heartily glad C# *didn't* copy.) Note that if you wanted several double arrays and several doubles, you could have (gasp) two declarations, one of `double[]` and one of `double`. Do you really think having the word `double` *twice* is cluttered?

Answer (score 3):

> ```
> private HashSet nodes = new HashSet;
> ```

is not valid Java.  Unlike JavaScript, the `new` operator in Java always requires a parenthesized argument list.

> ```
> private HashSet nodes = new HashSet(21);
> ```

differs from

> ```
> private HashSet[] nodes = new HashSet[21];
> ```

in that the former constructs one `HashSet` set that initially has space enough for 21 set items while the latter is an array of `21` null values that can be filled with references to sets.

---

> ```
> private HashSet nodes[];
> ```

declares a member variable that can refer to any array whose elements are of type `HashSet`.

> ```
> nodes = new HashSet[21];
> ```

creates an array with space for 21 `HashSet` references and assigns it to that member variable.

Remember that in Java, unlike in C, `HashSet[21]` is not a type so you can't just allocate space for an array in Java by doing

```
int[21] myints;
```

At some point you have to create an array via

- `new <type>[size]`,
- the abbreviated syntax `new <type> { element0, element1, element2, ... }`,
- or reflectively via `java.lang.reflect.Array.newInstance`.

Answer (score 1):

In Java, the declaration

```
private HashSet nodes[];
```

is equivalent to the declaration

```
private HashSet[] nodes;
```

It can be pronounced "an array of HashSets" or "a HashSet array."